# Is 请扫我的 an appropriate way ask the cashier to scan my phone for payment?

Tags: word-choice

In China nowadays, we mostly pay with things using our phones through 微信 (Wēixìn) = WeChat and 支付宝 (Zhīfùbǎo) = Alipay.  I often go to the shop, and get them to scan my phone for payment, whence I say:

> 请扫我的
>   qǐng sǎo wǒ de

I intend to mean "please scan my [phone]", leaving off 手机 (shǒujī) = phone for succinctness.  I want to check if this is suitable, and if not, what an appropriate alternative would be.

**Question**: Is 请扫我的 an appropriate way ask the cashier to scan my phone for payment?

---

*Edit*: corrected a typo (the original version had 清 instead of 请).

Comment: I usually ask 你扫我还是我扫你？, then take the appropriate method.

Comment: The very first question you should ask is 手机可以支付吗？ This will help clear about if they support phone payment and you prefer to pay with your phone. They might come back with 可以，微信 还是 支付宝？ If they don't mention 你扫我 还是 我扫你，then you should ask about that. Then you are ready to go.

Comment: Actually, just show the gesture to hand in your phone, and they immediately understand it, then either are going to scan your phone by their device, or ask you to scan code. In 99% of the time, you don't need to issue any word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, the whole sentence is

> 请扫我的二维码。
>
> Please scan my two-dimensional code.

Your shorter version is correct:

> 请扫我的。
>
> Please scan mine.

This sentence, however, can be used to hint that the cashier should scan your code as opposed to someone elses' (due to the presence of "mine").  The other version is very casual but often used:

> 请扫我。
>
> Please scan me.

which needs to be interpreted by a chain of context: to scan not you, but your something—which is your two-dimensional code, which is often your QR code.  Of course, it's often used because this context interpretation isn't hard.

Answer (score 4):

> 清扫我的
>   qīng sǎo wǒ de

Has a few issues.

- *please* is 请 qǐng and not 清 qīng
- 的 de is unnecessary here

请扫我 is okay but you're mostly likely leaving out essential information for the other person involved.

---

The person in charge of ringing you up usually wants to know if it is WeChat or Alipay that you are using. I believe they need to key something in on their registers before scanning you, I'm not totally sure but it always looks that way. The better way to aid the interaction would be for you to directly tell them method of payment you will be using. After they tell you the amount owed you can just say something like

- 好，支付宝哈
- 好，微信哈

Or you can change 哈 to whatever modal is popular in your vicinity.

Comment: Oh, the 清 is a typo.

Comment: @Becky李蓓 Yeah, I figured, but then I saw the pinyin and I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. But Sounds too foreign .

According to the conversation situation you described, I will ask which method for payment is acceptable, and if scanning the QR on my cellphone is OK, I will then show that QR to cashier quietly.

If you really need to say that , I will suggest "你扫我的吧". Adding 请 in daily conversation is one point making you sounds foreign.

Answer (score 0):

In real life this phrase should occur only when you have to inform the cashier that it will be you (instead of your companions) to pay. Otherwise, let’s see different scenarios.

1. Convenience shop & supermarket: The cashier will be telling you the total amount when he finishes scanning the barcodes of the items. If the merchants expects the customers to pay by scanning, a QR code should be displayed on a hanger or sticker around the cashier’s desk. If so, you may scan it and input the total amount; if not, you can simply show your QR code to the cashier, just in silence as native Chinese people do.
2. Restaurant with a central cashier desk (which is usually located near the door): These restaurants expect the customers to walk to the cashier desk to finish a payment. You might need to tell the cashier your table number. The cashier will the give you a list indicating the items and their prices with a total sum. You may figure out which side should be scanning the other’s QR code in the same way.

The fragmentation is caused by the flexibility of QR code payments: Verified merchants can scan to receive, while any user can scan to pay/transfer (and surely can show to receive). The receiving QR code doesn’t have to change over time, but PBOC did issue regulatory requirements to limit the daily total quota to 500 CNY of static QR code receiving.